# Order emails not sending to customer or admin magento 2.1.8?

Tags: order-email, server-setup, magento-2.1.8

I am facing an issue with sending the email.

When I triggered email then server log shows below information:

```
  pr  4 11:11:35 ip-172-31-3-44 postfix/smtp[90393]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
    Apr  4 11:11:35 ip-172-31-3-44 postfix/smtp[90390]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
    Apr  4 11:11:35 ip-172-31-3-44 postfix/smtp[90386]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
```

What are the means by that or how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Is it happened only for orders? are you sure you are using correct url and port? Seems like you are using IP6? Are you able to ping it? Did you change something? It works earlier?

Comment: All sales emails are not working, I have triggered email from root which is working.